# SAS for academic

Tags: sas

I've got an issue with SAS for Academics using web-based when I using statement proc print with by.
The output didn't show all value in tobe-group variable as below

Ex: I print table by variable "Country" which have many value: Venezuela, USA,....
but the output only display group of Venezuela

Code:

```
proc print data=data.customers ;
by country;
```

[image]

Comment: Show the log. Especially how data.customers is created and of the `Proc PRINT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the data is not sorted in ascending order of COUNTRY. That would make a lot of sense when Venezuela is listed as the first country.  Check the SAS LOG for an error message like this one:

```
1256  proc print data=sashelp.class;
1257    by sex;
1258  run;

ERROR: Data set SASHELP.CLASS is not sorted in ascending sequence. The current BY 
       group has Sex = M and the next BY group has Sex = F.
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
NOTE: There were 2 observations read from the data set SASHELP.CLASS.
NOTE: PROCEDURE PRINT used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
```

If the data is sorted by DESCENDING order of COUNTRY then tell PROC PRINT that fact.

```
proc print data=data.customers ;
  by descending country;
run;
```

If it is grouped by country but not actually sorted then use the NOTSORTED keyword.

```
proc print data=data.customers ;
  by country notsorted;
run;
```

And if it is not even grouped by country then sort it first.

```
proc sort data=data.customers ;
  by country ;
run;
proc print data=data.customers ;
  by country ;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you very much :3 It's very helpful and I fixed my problem <^.^>